# CONFLICT WITH "00:00:00" as END_TIME

Tags: sql, codeigniter, time, between

I have this query:

```
SELECT `s`.`time` , SUM( s.love ) AS total_love, SUM( s.sad ) AS total_sad, SUM( s.angry ) AS total_angry, SUM( s.happy ) AS total_happy
FROM (`employee_workshift` AS e)
JOIN `workshift` AS w ON `e`.`workshift_uuid` = `w`.`uuid`
JOIN `shift_summary` AS s ON `w`.`uuid` = `s`.`workshift_uuid`
WHERE `s`.`location_uuid` = '81956feb-3fd7-0e84-e9fe-b640434dfad0'
AND `e`.`employee_uuid` = '3866a979-bc5e-56cb-cede-863afc47b8b5'
AND `s`.`workshift_uuid` = '8c9dbd85-18a3-6ca9-e3f3-06eb602b6f38'
AND `s`.`time` >= CAST( '18:00:00' AS TIME )
AND `s`.`time` <= CAST( '00:00:00' AS TIME )
AND `s`.`date` LIKE '%2014-03%'
```

My problem is it returns "NULL" but when I changed my 'end_time' to "23:59:59", it returned the right data. I've got an idea to pull the hour of both 'start_time' and 'end_time' and then insert it in a loop to get everything between them.

```
$time_start = 15;
$time_end = 03;

So it should produce: 15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,00,01,02,03
```

Then I'll compare them all. But this would take a lot of line and effort than just simply using "BETWEEN". Or should I just use "in_array"? Have you encountered this? I hope someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

19:00 is certainly bigger then 00:00 - so your approach should not work.

Try using full timestamp (including date) to get all data you need.

Comment: Thank you @Jehy. Will try it out. Get back to you as soon as I get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query. I don't know your data structure so check `INNER JOIN` between `s` and `s1` tables. The join must be one row to one row - the difference only in date. Date of s1 rows must be earlier on 1 day than s table rows.

```
 SELECT s.time , SUM( s.love ) AS total_love, SUM( s.sad ) AS total_sad, SUM( s.angry ) AS total_angry, SUM( s.happy ) AS total_happy
    FROM (employee_workshift AS e)
    JOIN workshift AS w ON e.workshift_uuid = w.uuid
    JOIN shift_summary AS s ON w.uuid = s.workshift_uuid
    JOIN shift_summary AS s1 ON (w.uuid = s.workshift_uuid AND CAST(s.date as DATE)=CAST(s1.date as DATE)+1)
    WHERE s.location_uuid = '81956feb-3fd7-0e84-e9fe-b640434dfad0'
    AND e.employee_uuid = '3866a979-bc5e-56cb-cede-863afc47b8b5'
    AND s.workshift_uuid = '8c9dbd85-18a3-6ca9-e3f3-06eb602b6f38'
    AND s1.time >= CAST( '18:00:00' AS TIME )
    AND s.time <= CAST( '00:00:00' AS TIME )
    AND s.date LIKE '%2014-03%'
```

Comment: Thank you @MikkaRin. Will try it out. Get back to you as soon as I get the results.